# Обрисовать двумерный массив char

Tags: c++, curses

Нужно нарисовать карту игры. У меня есть `char Field[20][20]`, заполненный символами, где '#' означает стену. Нужно вывести в консоль эти стены.

Я не очень понимаю, как происходит процесс обрисовки. Вот моя идея:

```
void Spiel::initSpiel() {
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho(); 
    curs_set(false);
    nodelay(stdscr, true);
    keypad(stdscr, true);
    start_color();
    use_default_colors();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_RED);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_GREEN);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(4, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_BLACK);
}

void Spiel::showSpiel() {
    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
            if (Field[y][x] == '#') {
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
                mvprintw(y, x, "#");
                attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
            }
            else {
                attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
                mvprintw(y, x, " ");
                attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но в итоге ничего не происходит...

Comment: Судя по беглому взгляду (`гугл mvprintw`) куда-то в середину [curses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/printw.html), для собственно отрисовки, нужен еще, по крайней мере,  `refresh()`

Comment: @avp дай бог тебе здоровья

Comment: @avp, ответы в ответы?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а вот взял, да и написал ответ -)

Comment: @avp, ага, вижу :)

Answer (score 1):

Вставьте вызов `refresh();` для реального вывода символов на экран.

Когда вы вызываете функции вывода данных, такие как `mvprintw`, `printw`, `addch` и проч. [*curses*](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/index.html) на самом деле заносит данные в образ окна, который не отображается на экране постоянно. Для актуального вывода изображения на экран требуется вызвать `refresh`, которая проверит текущее состояние образа в памяти и отрисует на экране только реально изменившиеся символы.

Такой подход повышает эффективность кода и вносит дополнительную гибкость в работу программиста, позволяя несколько раз обновлять одни и те же области экрана без опасения, что это вызовет мерцание и т.п. эффекты.